# Getting an Error #2032: Stream Error with a Flex app running on Chrome only

Tags: flash, apache-flex, google-chrome, rpc, httpservice

I'm having a crazy error when I run my Flex application on Chrome when the server HTTP response it's an Internal Server Error (500) only. It works perfectly on Firefox and IE.

Using Fiddler, I know the server is giving the correct response. An 500 error with short XML data content holding the error message:

HEADER:

HTTP/1.1 500 LoginFailedException

Cache-Control: private

Content-Type: application/xml

Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5

X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3.85 Win32NT/.NET

X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Content-Length: 319

DATA:

```
<LoginDtoResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types"><ResponseStatus><ErrorCode>V2LoginFailedException</ErrorCode><Errors /><Message>Invalid username or password. Please try again.</Message><StackTrace i:nil="true" /></ResponseStatus></LoginDtoResponse>
```

But back to Chrome the response is totally missing, I'm getting this:

> HTTP request error
>   Server.Error.Request
>   Error #2032: Stream Error

Using Flex RPC HTTPService, I've tried changing the call headers and this is how I'm making the calls (GET and POST):

```
httpService = new HTTPService();
        httpService.resultFormat = "e4x";
        httpService.concurrency = "single";
        httpService.requestTimeout = 90;
        httpService.useProxy = false;
        httpService.headers["pragma"] = "public";
        httpService.headers["DNT"] = "1";
        httpService.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-store";
```

The system has a crossdomain.xml, I verified and it seems to be OK.

Also I've tried changing the Chrome Flash plugin with the Abobe Flash plugin with no results

[image]

And of course tried google it (spent day and half in fact) and it seems it used to happen a long time ago with IE 7, but never with Chrome.

Clearly something dodgy is going on, and it's driving me crazy! Please, any advice is welcome.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: chrome uses its own version of the flash player plugin, so its probably related to this - are you sure you switched it out with the adobe one properly?

Comment: Hello divillysausages, thanks for your comment. Yes, I'm 100% sure., I just added a print screen to my post.

Comment: The fact that it happens to both Adobe Flash and Pepper Flash (Chrome's built in Flash player) seems to point at the browser itself. Perhaps in this scenario, Chrome's not handling the 500 error like it should (w/respect to Flash). Is this a new problem that started recently (new version of Chrome?), can you try other versions of Chrome? As a trouble shooting measure, is it possible to return some other HTTP status code than 500?

Comment: Hi Sunil! Thanks for your ideas. I've tried with a previous Chrome version and the problem still there. I've tried returning 5xx Server Errors as well but still the same. I cannot change the server response to a different kind because the server side and UI were designed to respond/handle 5xx, as you can see it will take a lot of work to change all that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case work fine in this version on Flash

[image]